# Resize Notepad based on holding frame

Tags: perl, resize, tk-toolkit, tkx

I'm trying to get the notepad to expand when dragging the main
window .... and suggestions? I have it to where it reads the screen size but it won't keep the changing size of the window. All my attempts of add a loop have failed... is there anyway to create a loop or a constant call back?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Tkx;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Cwd;
use Tkx;
Tkx::package_require("Tktable");
Tkx::package_require("tile");
Tkx::package_require("style");
Tkx::style__use("as", -priority => 70);
Tkx::package_require('widget::scrolledwindow');
Tkx::package_require("BWidget");


our $VERSION = "1.00";
(my $progname = $0) =~ s,.*[\\/],,;

 my $mw = Tkx::widget->new(".");
$mw->g_wm_title("Wikiget");
$mw->g_wm_minsize(500, 200);

cow();

Tkx::MainLoop();
exit;

sub cow
{
my $sw = $mw->new_ScrolledWindow();
my $sf = $sw->new_ScrollableFrame();
$sw->g_pack(-fill => "both", -expand => 1); $sw->setwidget($sf);
my $printer_frame = Tkx::widget->new($sf->getframe());


Tkx::update('idletasks');
    my $x = int((Tkx::winfo('width',  $mw))- 10);
    my $y = int((Tkx::winfo('height', $mw)) - 50);


my $nb = $printer_frame->new_ttk__notebook(-height => $y, -width => $x);
$nb->g_pack(-fill => "both", -expand => 1);
my $fm1 = $nb->new_ttk__frame;
my $fm2 = $nb->new_ttk__frame;

$fm1->new_label(-text => 'Test1Test1Test1')->g_pack(qw/-anchor nw/);
$fm2->new_label(-text => 'Test2Test2Test2')->g_pack(qw/-anchor nw/);


$nb->add($fm1, -text => 'One');
$nb->add($fm2, -text => 'Two');
}
```